# How to check for a node with a immediate ancestor using descendants method?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How do I get the values of a node whose immediate ancestor is another node (using `descendants` method), e.x. below is a small portion of a xml file

```
<sec id="s2">
 <label>2.</label>
 <title>THE MORPHOLOGY OF CHONDRAE TENDIANEAE OF ATRIOVENTRICULAR VALVES HEARTS NEWBORNS AND INFANTS</title>
 <p>According to the macroscopic</p>
 <fig id="F1">
  <label>Figure 1.</label>
  <caption><p>Tendon string valvular heart baby infants. 1 - mastoid muscle, 2 - tendon strings.</p></caption>
  <graphic xlink:href="00062_psisdg9066_90661R_page_2_1.jpg"/>
 </fig>
 <fig id="F2">
  <label>Figure 2.</label>
  <caption><p>Tendon string valvular heart newborn baby. 1 - mastoid muscle, 2 - tendon strings.</p></caption>
  <graphic xlink:href="00062_psisdg9066_90661R_page_2_2.jpg"/>
 </fig>
</sec>
<sec id="s3">
 <label>3.</label>
 <title>EXPERIMENTAL RESULTS AND DISCUSSION</title>
 <p>Material studies provided three-sided and mitral valve that were taken from 8 hearts of stillborn children and four dead infants.</p>
</sec>
```

I want all the values of the node `<label>` which has a immediate ancestor node `<sec>`. i.e. in this case the value should be `2.` and `3.`
If I do

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(@"D:\test\sample.XML");
var x = from a in doc.Descendants("label")
        where a.Ancestors("sec").Attributes("id").Any()
        select a.Value;
```

I get `2., Figure 1., Figure 2., 3.`, what other conditions do I have to add to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ancestors("sec")` will find all ancestors, no matter how deeply nested, not the immediate ancestors, so that's not going to help.
You need to get only the first ancestor. Since `Ancestors()` will return them in reverse document order, we can simply get the first.

```
var x = from a in doc.Descendants("label")
    let ancestor = a.Ancestors().First()
    where ancestor.Name == "sec" && ancestor.Attributes("id").Any()
    select a.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, how do I check if `x` is null/empty in this case , `if (x==null) { Console.WriteLine("No such value found!");  }` does not seem to work

Comment: @Bumba `x` will not be null, but it can be empty. So you can use `DefaultIfEmpty()`